# Does anyone has "white screen" issues with intel xdk?

Tags: intel-xdk

I made an app, just pages nothing special with app framework, i run the app on my device it is running ok, but when i "pause" my app and then return to it i am getting a white screen, i can remove it only if i tap the screen. Keep in mind that i downloaded app preview from google play and i am getting the same white screen. 
Could someone help? Thank you!

Edited:

i found out that the issue is not caused by the android build, but it has to do with the files inside www\app_framework\2.1\
first i was searching and editing all the #fff and i found out that the line inside

www\app_framework\2.1\css\af.ui.min.js

-ms-viewport{width:device-width}#afui{background:#fff;color:#53575E}

it is the white background that we see when we open the app framework, so i edited the af.ui.min.js and i added the background: to green, (keep in mind that i have an image background inside the xdk) i build it i installed on my device and then the issue with the tap white screen turned into the same issue but now the screen that i have to tap is green ! it's like something is forcing the app framework to have the white backgound (the one we see when we open the app framework), i can't remove the white background and i can't make it transparent i deleted the background:#fff but i still got the same white/green or any color i make that line above.

After that i deleted all files that are inside www\app_framework\2.1\ and i built the app, yes everything was broken but my main thought was to see if i would have to tap the screen again, and in the end i got no white screen!
So there is something wrong inside the www\app_framework\2.1\ !

Comment: I'm not sure this is the same issue you are having - have you seen this thread? https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=2503

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, just in case someone has a similar problem, this is how I dealt with it.

1. Ensure you have a very good internet connection, if the connection is poor, most likely the intel XDK will have problems uploading or downloading your app completely.
2. You can opt to download your built app from your INTEL registered email - they always mail you a link to your built app - instead of downloading it via the XDK.
3. Try deleting previous app build in your INTEL XDK server, go to https://appcenter.html5tools-software.intel.com/csd/ControlPanel.aspx to see a list of your uploaded INTEL XDK app. After deleting do a fresh build.
4. Avoid editing your source code as the Intel XDK is uploading your app.

Cheers, enjoy your coding ;)